# Why is my "cut_button.destroy()" not destroying my customtkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm using customtkinter to create a mini-python version of "Word"! Within my code is a variable that automatically refreshes ever few milliseconds and is designed to detect if the player is highlighting something in the CTkTextbox (textbox). If it detects it, it reveals a button that copies the selected text to the users clipboard and deletes the text.

The problem is when It is suppose to remove it self, it gets to that point but it does actually remove itself. It runs the command, but the button stays!

If it helps, I am using the latest version of customtkinter, using macOS Sonoma, and on python version 3.12.2 using Visual Studio Code as my IDE.

```
# WHAT TO ADD NEXT
#
# - Bold and Underline Buttons underneath font size
# - Maybe a font changer??
# - Copy and Paste Buttons (per OS)


import customtkinter
import os
from PIL import Image


current_font_size = 17
textbox = None
path_to_folder = None
main_window = None
word_count = "Words: 0"
cut_button = None



checkmark_icon = customtkinter.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open("checkmark.png"),
                                        size=(15, 15))
copy_icon = customtkinter.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open("copy.png"),
                                   size=(19, 19))
paste_icon = customtkinter.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open("paste.png"),
                                    size=(19, 19))


def cut_variable():
    global textbox, main_window, cut_button

    def cut_variable():
        text_selected = textbox.get(
            customtkinter.SEL_FIRST, customtkinter.SEL_LAST)
        main_window.clipboard_append(text_selected)
        textbox.delete(customtkinter.SEL_FIRST, customtkinter.SEL_LAST)
        main_window.update()
        return cut_button

    cut_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_window,
                                         fg_color='#4e4f52',
                                         corner_radius=8,
                                         text="Cut?",
                                         border_width=1,
                                         border_color="#4e5255",
                                         hover_color="#414245",
                                         bg_color="#2b2b2b",
                                         width=60,
                                         height=25,
                                         command=cut_variable)
    cut_button.place(x=4,
                     y=572)


def start_textbox():
    global main_window, textbox
    textbox_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(main_window,
                                           width=900,
                                           height=472,
                                           border_width=2,
                                           corner_radius=0)
    textbox_frame.place(x=0,
                        y=98)

    # -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- #
    textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(textbox_frame,
                                       width=900,
                                       height=470,
                                       font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=current_font_size))
    textbox.grid(sticky="n")


def new_file_prompt():
    global path_to_folder, textbox, path
    file_window = customtkinter.CTk()
    file_window.title("Create New File")
    file_window.geometry("300x153")
    file_window.attributes('-topmost', True)

    # --------------------------- Labels and Stuff --------------------------- #

    label1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(file_window,
                                    text="Filename",
                                    bg_color="#242424",
                                    font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=15,
                                                               weight="bold"))
    label1.pack(padx=10,
                pady=3,
                side="top",
                anchor="nw")

    label2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(file_window,
                                    text="Custom Path",
                                    bg_color="#242424",
                                    font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=15,
                                                               weight="bold"))
    label2.pack(padx=10,
                pady=7,
                side="top",
                anchor="nw")

    label3 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(file_window,
                                    text="All changes will be saved",
                                    bg_color="#242424",
                                    font=customtkinter.CTkFont("italic", size=10))
    label3.place(x=10,
                 y=121)

    # -------------------------- Buttons and Stuff -------------------------- #

    file_extension = ".txt"

    filename = customtkinter.CTkEntry(file_window,
                                      font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=13),
                                      height=9,
                                      width=100,
                                      placeholder_text="filename")
    filename.place(x=130,
                   y=5)

    filextension_var = customtkinter.StringVar(value=".txt")

    def file_extension_variable(choice):
        file_extension = str(choice)
        print(file_extension)
        return file_extension

    filextension = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(file_window,
                                               values=[".txt", ".doc"],
                                               variable=filextension_var,
                                               width=60,
                                               height=23,
                                               bg_color="#242323",
                                               command=file_extension_variable)
    filextension.place(x=235,
                       y=5)

    custompath = 0

    choice_var = customtkinter.IntVar()

    path_to_folder = None

    def variable_no():
        global custompath, path_to_folder
        if path_to_folder is not None:
            path_to_folder.destroy()
        custompath = 0
        return custompath

    no_button = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(file_window,
                                             bg_color="#242323",
                                             width=7,
                                             height=3,
                                             text="No",
                                             font=customtkinter.CTkFont(
                                                 size=12),
                                             variable=choice_var,
                                             value=1,
                                             command=variable_no)
    no_button.place(x=245,
                    y=45)

    def variable_yes():
        global custompath, path_to_folder
        path_to_folder = customtkinter.CTkEntry(file_window,
                                                font=customtkinter.CTkFont(
                                                    size=13),
                                                height=9,
                                                width=110,
                                                placeholder_text="/path/to/folder")
        path_to_folder.place(x=184,
                             y=75)
        custompath = 1
        return path_to_folder, custompath

    yes_button = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(file_window,
                                              bg_color="#242323",
                                              width=7,
                                              height=3,
                                              text="Yes",
                                              font=customtkinter.CTkFont(
                                                  size=12),
                                              variable=choice_var,
                                              value=2,
                                              command=variable_yes)
    yes_button.place(x=185,
                     y=45)

    def create_file(file_extension, content, custompath):
        global path, textbox
        if custompath == 1:
            global path_to_folder
            filename_and_extension = (filename.get()) + file_extension
            path = str(path_to_folder.get()) + "/" + \
                str(filename_and_extension)
            with open(path, 'w') as file_:
                file_.write(content)
                file_.close()
                file_window.destroy()
        elif custompath == 0:
            current_dir = os.getcwd()
            filename_and_extension = (filename.get()) + file_extension
            path1 = str(current_dir) + "/" + "Written_Works"

            if not os.path.exists(path1):
                os.makedirs(path1)
            if os.path.exists(path1):
                pass

            path = path1 + "/" + str(filename_and_extension)
            with open(path, 'w') as file_:
                file_.write(content)
                file_.close()
                file_window.destroy()

    # Inside save_textbox_prompt function

    def create_file_callback():
        global path_to_folder, textbox, path
        content = textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")  # Get content from textbox
        create_file(file_extension, content, custompath)

    create_file_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(file_window,
                                                 bg_color="#242323",
                                                 width=90,
                                                 height=20,
                                                 text="Create File",
                                                 command=create_file_callback)
    create_file_button.place(x=205,
                             y=125)

    file_window.mainloop()


def save_file_callback():
    global path, textbox
    if path:  # Check if path is not None
        with open(path, 'w') as file_:
            content = textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")  # Get content from textbox
            file_.write(content)
            file_.close()


def constant_update():
    global textbox, word_counter_label, main_window
    # -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- #
    # ---------------- Update Textbox and Word Counter Label ------------------- #
    text = textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    word_count_before = len(text.split())
    word_count = "Words:", str(word_count_before)
    word_counter_label.configure(text=word_count)
    word_counter_label.update()
    # ------------------------- Check for Highlight ---------------------------- #
    if textbox.tag_ranges("sel"):
        # Create Buttons that will have different functions
        cut_variable()
        pass
    if not textbox.tag_ranges('sel'):
        if cut_button:  # Check if cut_button exists
            cut_button.destroy()  # Destroy the button if it exists
        pass
    # -------------------------- Update Everything ---------------------------- #
    main_window.after(300, constant_update)


# _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_- Main -_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_ #
def main():
    global main_window
    main_window = customtkinter.CTk()
    main_window.geometry("900x600")
    main_window.title("Word")
    main_window.resizable(False, False)
    main_window._apply_appearance_mode("dark")

    # ------------------- Top Part ------------------- #
    top_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(main_window,
                                       width=900,
                                       height=99,
                                       border_width=2,
                                       corner_radius=1)
    top_frame.pack(padx=0,
                   pady=0,
                   side="top")
    # -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- #
    new_file_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_window,
                                              height=26,
                                              width=150,
                                              text="New File",
                                              corner_radius=4,
                                              border_width=1,
                                              fg_color="#242424",
                                              border_color="#333232",
                                              bg_color="#2b2b2b",
                                              font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=14,
                                                                         weight="bold"),
                                              command=new_file_prompt)
    new_file_button.place(x=5,
                          y=6)
    # -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- #
    load_file_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_window,
                                               height=26,
                                               width=150,
                                               text="Load File",
                                               corner_radius=4,
                                               border_width=1,
                                               fg_color="#242424",
                                               border_color="#333232",
                                               bg_color="#2b2b2b",
                                               font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=14,
                                                                          weight="bold"))
    load_file_button.place(x=5,
                           y=36)
    # -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- #
    save_file_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_window,
                                               height=26,
                                               width=150,
                                               text="Save File",
                                               corner_radius=4,
                                               border_width=1,
                                               fg_color="#242424",
                                               border_color="#333232",
                                               bg_color="#2b2b2b",
                                               font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=14,
                                                                          weight="bold"),
                                               command=save_file_callback)
    save_file_button.place(x=5,
                           y=66)
    # -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- #

    def clear_textbox():
        textbox.delete("1.0", "end")  # Clear the textbox

    clear_textbox_text = """Clear
Texbox"""

    clear_textbox_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_window,
                                                   width=75,
                                                   height=42,
                                                   text=clear_textbox_text,
                                                   corner_radius=4,
                                                   border_width=1,
                                                   fg_color="#242424",
                                                   border_color="#333232",
                                                   bg_color="#2b2b2b",
                                                   hover_color="#135970",
                                                   font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=12,
                                                                              weight="bold"),
                                                   command=clear_textbox)
    clear_textbox_button.place(x=159,
                               y=6)
    # -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- #
    options_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_window,
                                             width=75,
                                             height=40,
                                             text="Options",
                                             corner_radius=4,
                                             border_width=1,
                                             fg_color="#242424",
                                             border_color="#333232",
                                             bg_color="#2b2b2b",
                                             hover_color="#135970",
                                             font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=12,
                                                                        weight="bold"))
    options_button.place(x=159,
                         y=52)
    # -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- #
    size_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(main_window,
                                        height=23,
                                        width=80,
                                        placeholder_text=current_font_size,
                                        font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=13),
                                        bg_color="#2b2b2b",
                                        border_color='#555b5e',
                                        placeholder_text_color="white",
                                        corner_radius=4,
                                        border_width=1)
    size_entry.place(x=240,
                     y=7)

    def change_size():
        current_font_size = int(size_entry.get())
        textbox.configure(state="normal")

        textbox.configure(font=("SF Display", current_font_size))

    size_entry_confirm = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_window,
                                                 fg_color='#353638',
                                                 width=23,
                                                 height=23,
                                                 corner_radius=3,
                                                 image=checkmark_icon,
                                                 border_width=1,
                                                 border_color='#4e5255',
                                                 background_corner_colors=[
                                                     '#555b5e', '#353638', '#353638', '#555b5e'],
                                                 bg_color='#2b2b2b',
                                                 text="",
                                                 hover_color="#137022",
                                                 command=change_size)
    size_entry_confirm.place(x=298,
                             y=7)
    # -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- #
    bold_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_window,
                                          fg_color='#353638',
                                          width=25,
                                          height=25,
                                          corner_radius=4,
                                          text="B",
                                          border_width=1,
                                          font=customtkinter.CTkFont(
                                              size=12, weight="bold"),
                                          border_color="#4e5255",
                                          hover_color="#136d70",
                                          bg_color="#2b2b2b")
    bold_button.place(x=240,
                      y=34)

    underline_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_window,
                                               fg_color='#353638',
                                               width=25,
                                               height=25,
                                               corner_radius=4,
                                               text="U",
                                               border_width=1,
                                               font=customtkinter.CTkFont(
                                                   size=12, underline=True),
                                               border_color="#4e5255",
                                               hover_color="#136d70",
                                               bg_color="#2b2b2b")
    underline_button.place(x=269,
                           y=34)

    italic_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_window,
                                            fg_color='#353638',
                                            width=25,
                                            height=25,
                                            corner_radius=4,
                                            text="I",
                                            border_width=1,
                                            font=customtkinter.CTkFont(
                                                "SF Display Italic", size=12),
                                            border_color="#4e5255",
                                            hover_color="#136d70",
                                            bg_color="#2b2b2b")
    italic_button.place(x=298,
                        y=34)
    # -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- #
    copy_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_window,
                                          fg_color='#353638',
                                          corner_radius=4,
                                          text="",
                                          border_width=1,
                                          border_color="#4e5255",
                                          hover_color="#136d70",
                                          bg_color="#2b2b2b",
                                          width=39,
                                          height=28,
                                          image=copy_icon)
    copy_button.place(x=240,
                      y=63)

    paste_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(main_window,
                                           fg_color='#353638',
                                           corner_radius=4,
                                           text="",
                                           border_width=1,
                                           border_color="#4e5255",
                                           hover_color="#136d70",
                                           bg_color="#2b2b2b",
                                           width=39,
                                           height=28,
                                           image=paste_icon)
    paste_button.place(x=284,
                       y=63)
    # ------------------ Middle Part ----------------- #
    start_textbox()
    # ------------------- End Part ------------------- #
    bottom_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(main_window,
                                          width=900,
                                          height=33,
                                          border_width=1,
                                          corner_radius=4)
    bottom_frame.place(x=0,
                       y=569)

    global word_counter_label
    word_counter_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(main_window,
                                                text=word_count,
                                                font=customtkinter.CTkFont(
                                                    size=14),
                                                bg_color="#2b2b2b",
                                                text_color="#d4d4d4",
                                                height=26)
    word_counter_label.place(x=810,
                             y=570)
    # -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- #

    # --------------- Constant Update --------------- #
    constant_update()

    main_window.mainloop()


main()
```

Comment: In the outer `cut_variable` where you create `cut_button` you don't check if there is already a button, so you create multiple buttons but only destroy the last one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please try to reduce the amount of code in your example. If a function or widget isn't necessary in order to reproduce this problem, please don't include it. There seems to be several widgets and functions that match that description.